# Use Get Field Value tool to calculate field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, field-calculator, arctoolbox

I am running a summary statistic on a clip to get acre counts by area type. I want to then add a second field that has the acre count from the total area. A third field be added so that it shows as the percentage of each acre type as compared to the whole area.

First field = `Summary Statistics of area type by acre count`

Second field = `Total acres of project area` <--- **This is where I am having trouble**

Third field =  `(([first field]/[second field]) * 100)`

The problem is, I am trying to get the value from the initial project area using the Get Field Value tool. I am able to do this but when using the Calculate Field tool to calculate the third field, I do not know how to get this option.

Can I set the value from the Get Field Value to a variable then in the Field Calculator use Python to call the variable? Will it recognize the variable?

Comment: Can you clarify where it is that you are trying to do this? (in a python script, in model builder or just using field calculator)

Comment: Sorry, I am doing this in model builder. I can do all of this in the field calculator but I want to make a model builder tool to do everything at once much more quickly.

Comment: "get value from the initial project area", are these values stored in a different table or is all of this info in one table?

Comment: That value is coming from another separate feature class.

Comment: Can you join the two layers spatially or non-spatially, if so you could use python within field calculator?

Comment: The project area has a single value for the whole area, the total acres. The next layer is a multi polygon feature class that has many values, the acre count for each smaller area. Since area types repeat, a summary statistic tool is performed at this point. It is within the summary statistic output that I am looking to do this. How could I join in the value for the total acres for a field in the summary statistic output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in ModelBuilder using Get Field Value on your project layer (against pre-calculated area or acre field), and using in-line variable substitution within a Row Selection iterator, and calculating using field calculation on the sum stat table.

See graphics below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Get field value doesn't seem to exist in arc 10.2... any work around?

Comment: Never mind. Get field values is part of the model builder only toolkit. "The only way you can gain access to the tools within the ModelBuilder toolbox is from the Insert menu in the ModelBuilder window."